# How to reduce options for units of measurement to just miles and km for proximity search

Tags: 7, views, forms, location

Using geofield with Views and exposed filters to the user to search for things on the map within a certain radius of a particular location.

I only require miles and kilometres as units of measurement, not: Yards, Feet, Nautical Miles. Any way to omit these?

They are defined in the module geofield's file, `geofield.elements.inc` code:

```
/**
 * Returns options for radius of the Earth.
 */

function geofield_radius_options() {
  return array(
    GEOFIELD_KILOMETERS => t('Kilometers'),
    GEOFIELD_METERS => t('Meters'),
    GEOFIELD_MILES => t('Miles'),
    GEOFIELD_YARDS => t('Yards'),
    GEOFIELD_FEET => t('Feet'),
    GEOFIELD_NAUTICAL_MILES => t('Nautical Miles'),
  );
}
```

But I don't want to hack this and remove them.

The approach I am expecting to use would be to implement `hook_form_alter` in my own module and remove the options from there.

But is there a better way?

Comment: Feature request raised to remove unwanted units: https://drupal.org/node/2050061

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is simply using CSS.

The select list is built like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="6371">Kilometres</option>
  <option value="6371000">Metres</option>
  <option value="3959">Miles</option>
  <option value="6975175">Yards</option>
  <option value="20925525">Feet</option>
  <option value="3444">Nautical Miles</option>
</select>
```

You could hide the undesired values with the following style (in this case only "kilometres" and "miles" remain):

```
option[value="6371000"], 
option[value="6975175"],
option[value="20925525"],
option[value="3444"]{
  display: none;
}
```

**If you're only using one value**, it may look a bit silly to have a select box of it. You could disguise it as regular text though. Make sure the font is identical to the rest, remove the border, set a width to the container of the select list and hide everything seeping out of it, whilst making the select list a tad longer (thus the dropdown arrow gets hidden by the overflow):

```
.form-item-field-geofield-distance-unit{
    width: 90px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

select{
    width: 120px;
    border: 0;
    cursor: text;
}
```

Alternatively (Bootstrap 3):

```
.form-item-field-geofield-distance-unit select{
    border: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none;
    cursor: text;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

Adjust the margins or paddings if necessary…

Comment: +1 Neat answer - that hiding of options could be useful in other areas

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really in the form, via hook_form_alter(). It's an element of a form component, so you really need to implement hook_element_info_alter(), and add a "process" callback to the stack.

In that process callback you can then update the options:

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_element_info_alter().
 */
function YOURTHEMEORMODULE_element_info_alter(&$type) {
  $type['geofield_proximity']['#process'][] = '_alter_proximity';
}

function _alter_proximity($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  //Create dropdown for units
  $reduced_options = array(
    GEOFIELD_MILES => 'Miles',
    GEOFIELD_KILOMETERS => 'Kilometers'
  );
  $element['unit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $reduced_options,
    '#title' => t('Unit'),
    '#default_value' => !empty($element['#default_value']['unit']) ? $element['#default_value']['unit'] : GEOFIELD_KILOMETERS,
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
  );
  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My own answer (incomplete *so far* - will update when I've figured it out (feel free to chip in ;) ) but "on the right track" I think. Incomplete because I haven't figured out how to access the menu option elements from the hook module, `Devel` module `dpm()` is not helpful at directing me as to how to 'get at' the menu drop down form options in the $form array.)

I have started to write this hook override - which I have confirm is called in my custom module `cgformutils` in file `cgformutils.module` :-

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter().
 */
function cgformutils_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-locally-page') 
  {
     dpm($form);
  }

  // menu modifying code to go here:

  // I need to figure out what to put here, 
  // dpm() is not helpful at directing me as to how
  // to 'get at' the menu drop down form options in the $form array
  // in order to remove some - php unset them

  return $form;  
}
```

Here's an annotated screen shot for my explanation as to why `Devel` module `dpm()` function is not helping me work out how to access the menu drop down options from the `$form` array:

[image]

Comment: Other appoaches might be the better exposed filters module - though out of the box this doesn't provide what I need, though it does provide an API - but if I have to write code I might as well continue with my approach to write a hook. Another option is the views hacks module.